# What do you call a set of elements not including their ends?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have a set of objects, an example would be this set of letters.

```
{A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I}
```

I need to call each part (or group of parts) with short single words.  Letter "A" is the Head; "I" is the Tail; Both Head and Tail are called Ends. each element is called a Segment.

So my question is, what do we call the middle segments B through H, in a short single word?

- It can't be 'Middle/Center' because it could only refer to E.
- It can't be 'Segment' because it includes the Head and Tail.
- Basically the word needs to mean (w/o ambiguity) the segments not including the Head & Tail.
- Doesn't need to be formal, like what I did w/ Head/Tail, which could've been just Start/End or First/Last.

Ironically, it's my homework on programming and naming function/methods, but this is more on language so I decided to post it here.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Naming functions/methods is expressly off-topic here. Presicely because as far as the language is concerned, you can name them anything at all, and what is best is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: Median would be problematic, but middle should be fine.

Comment: @RegDwigнt: I agree, but our instructor is pushing for simplistic naming conventions, which is really neat in my opionion.  But then again, posting this at StackOverflow, is a bit off-topic too since the focus is finding a word.  Anyway, thanks for the heads-up, I'll keep that in mind in my future questions. :')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some higher maths distinguish elements along edges from others by calling the edge points *boundaries*, the outer ones *exterior*, [and the inner ones *interior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_%28topology%29). (In this case, one might say: A and I are boundaries; B through H are interior; and J to Z is exterior.) Abbreviating these may breach good form in some programming languages: *ints* is too much like **int** for *integer*; *intern* (or *internal*) may be too close to C's **extern**; etc.

It's a little grotesque, but [*innards*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/innards) continues in the tradition of *head* and *tail*. TFD yields as one definition

> The inner parts, as of a machine.

but I think its other definition of *entrails* comes more readily to mind, particularly if it's used with *head* and *tail*.

If the set {A-I} has the name *X*, I recommend these less-technical terms, where the first is for head/tail and the second is for the rest:

- *X_outer*; *X_inner*
- *X_ends*; *X_mids*

Comment: Cool, really appreciate explaining the Math and Cases in a technical way.  Thank you, I've chosen "Innards" because Head & Tail reminds me of a Snake.  I'll credit you and this answer in my source code.  Appreciated it, Mr. Dingo.

Comment: here's a reference, sorta - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_(topology)

Answer (score 0):

intermediates? or links, middle elements, middle parts

Answer (score 0):

"Body" would probably be the best analogy to go with Head or Tail.  You will have to decide what happens in the degenerate cases where the set is totally empty, has one, two or exactly three members, as one or more of these will be empty.

Comment: The snag is that _body_ is an overworked word already, and pressing it into this usage could lead to confusion. Perhaps 'thorax' would be less potentially ambiguous (if rather weirder-sounding).

Comment: And Head and Tail are not?  So if the entire thing is a Clump, then Clump_Head() returns the head, Clump_Body() returns a clump with the Body elements in it, and so on.

Comment: 'Body' already has a sense in matrix terminology.

Answer (score 0):

Consider *torso*, which per [en.wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/torso#Noun) means “The part of the (human) body from the neck to the groin, that is, the body excluding the head and limbs”.  In this case, it would be less ambiguous with a word for that part of the body from the neck to the ankles, but to most English speakers I think *torso* will connote clipping off end elements.